# How to append after Regex Search in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to convert a MySQL dump into SQLite database, for database migration. I need to edit the date to append time, so for example 2018-09-19 should be converted to 2018-09-19 00:00:00.00. The reason for this format has to do with how our application works. This is the solution I came up with but it doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>){
  <Other Stuff>
  ....
  s/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\[/$1[00:00:00.00]][/
print;
}
```

For testing I created a test.txt file with just for testing

```
2019-03-06
```

And in command line or terminal I used the following command to test if the append works.

```
 perl -pe  's/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\[/$1[00:00:00.00]][/' < test.txt > testout.txt
```

This gives a clear error of:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "00:" Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Using this @dada's solution that looks like this gives no error but also doesn't append the 00:00:00.00 at the end of the line

The Expected output should be

```
2019-03-06 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Please, describe what "it doesn't work" means, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your regex does match `2018-09-19[`.  You might want to use `${1}` instead of `$1` in the replacement side though, or `$1\[` instead of `$1[`.

Comment: Your problem statement doesn't match your code. the code looks for square brackets.

Comment: @Dada hey thanks for the feedback. I added a verifiable method that I was using to just test the regex. I'll try out your recommendations i'm sure i just have a small problem somewhere.

Comment: @jhnc Not sure I understand doesn't my code try to match a date format namely this section of the code `([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem statement says you want to turn:

```
2018-09-19
```

into:

```
2018-09-19 00:00:00.00
```

However, your code is:

```
s/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\[/$1[00:00:00.00]][/
```

Using `/x` we can write it a bit more legibly as:

```
s/
    (
        [12]\d{3}                    # year
        -                            # hyphen
        ( 0[1-9] | 1[0-2] )          # month (saved as $2)
        -                            # hyphen
        ( 0[1-9] | [12]\d | 3[01] )  # day (saved as $3)
    )                                # save this as $1
    \[                               # square bracket 
/$1[00:00:00.00]][/x
```

From this, it is clear that `2018-09-19` does not match because it does not end with a square bracket.

The replacement value is:

```
$1[00:00:00.00]][
```

This (tries to) say:

- lookup index `00:00:00.00` in array `@1` and substitute value
- append `][`

However this is not valid perl and not what you wanted anyway.

What is happening is that instead of `$x` + `[y]` (scalar followed by string value), perl is seeing `$x[y]` (value from array). To prevent this, either use braces ( `${x}[y]` ) or escape the bracket ( `$x\[y]` ). This results in:

```
${1}[00:00:00.00]][
```

which is still not what the problem said was needed as the zeros are wrapped in brackets.

To get what you say you want, remove the `\[` from the end of the search part and remove the unnecessary brackets from the replacement part:

```
s/
    (
        [12]\d{3}
        - ( 0[1-9] | 1[0-2] )
        - ( 0[1-9] | [12]\d | 3[01] )
    )
    # no bracket here
/$1 00:00:00.00/x;  # no brackets here
```

---

Note that your code as given has another bug which is that the final `print` needs to be separated from the `s///` by a semi-colon.

Comment: This makes so much more sense. Thank you so much for the help man, I really appreciate it!